# Geb not pointing to right page after closing confirm dialog in new window

Tags: selenium, testing, groovy, automated-tests, geb

I am doing test automation with geb in groovy, curently dealing with scenario like: 
First, I am in parent window, from there I open new window and do some search there, Clicking on the search result generates a confirm dialogue and updates the value in parent page, Bypassing the dialog with withConfirm(). then I come to parent window but nothing executes after that. I think geb is getting confused between pages.

```
In parent Page
  open new window 
  search for something  
  click on the first search result
  clicking on it opens a confirm dialog 
  click okay and close the new window 
continue with parent window
```

My code looks like:

```
withNewWindow(close: false,wait:true,{$(button that opens new window).click()}) {
        waitFor{
            title == "title"
        }
        withConfirm(wait: true){$(cause to open confirm dialog).click()}
        }
$("input[name='button'][id='SAVE_FOOTER']").click()
}
```

Error:

```
Caught: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Browsing context has been discarded
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-NAFK3F3', ip: '10.1.10.195', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 65.0.2, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.24.0, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 12824, moz:profile: C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local..., moz:shutdownTimeout: 60000, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, platformVersion: 10.0, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 2c0c768c-785f-49d4-bdff-186566e722dd
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Browsing context has been discarded
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-NAFK3F3', ip: '10.1.10.195', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 65.0.2, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.24.0, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 12824, moz:profile: C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local..., moz:shutdownTimeout: 60000, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, platformVersion: 10.0, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 2c0c768c-785f-49d4-bdff-186566e722dd
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at geb.js.JavascriptInterface.execjs(JavascriptInterface.groovy:66)
    at geb.js.JavascriptInterface.exec(JavascriptInterface.groovy:56)
    at geb.js.DefaultAlertAndConfirmSupport.popLastDialogFunctionOnto(DefaultAlertAndConfirmSupport.groovy:114)
    at geb.js.DefaultAlertAndConfirmSupport.captureDialog(DefaultAlertAndConfirmSupport.groovy:168)
    at geb.js.DefaultAlertAndConfirmSupport.captureConfirm(DefaultAlertAndConfirmSupport.groovy:182)
    at geb.js.DefaultAlertAndConfirmSupport.withConfirm(DefaultAlertAndConfirmSupport.groovy:54)
    at geb.js.DefaultAlertAndConfirmSupport.withConfirm(DefaultAlertAndConfirmSupport.groovy)
    at geb.js.AlertAndConfirmSupport$withConfirm.call(Unknown Source)
    at geb.Page.withConfirm(Page.groovy:130)
    at geb.Browser.methodMissing(Browser.groovy:249)
    at geb.Browser.invokeMethod(Browser.groovy)
    at CRMPageExample$_run_closure1$_closure3.doCall(CRMPageExample.groovy:149)
    at CRMPageExample$_run_closure1$_closure3.doCall(CRMPageExample.groovy)
    at geb.Browser.withNewWindow(Browser.groovy:798)
    at CRMPageExample$_run_closure1.doCall(CRMPageExample.groovy:137)
    at CRMPageExample$_run_closure1.doCall(CRMPageExample.groovy)
    at geb.Browser.drive(Browser.groovy:128)
    at geb.Browser$drive$0.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at geb.Browser.drive(Browser.groovy:98)
    at geb.Browser$drive.call(Unknown Source)
    at CRMPageExample.run(CRMPageExample.groovy:97)
1552494416789   Marionette  INFO    Stopped listening on port 52107
[Parent 12824, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 332
[Child 2628, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 332
[Child 2628, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file [Parent 12824, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 332
[Child 8068, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 332
[Child 8068, Chrome_ChildThre
###!!! [Child][MessageChannel::SendAndWait] Error: Channel error: cannot send/recv
```

Methods I tried but seems useless

```
waitFor{
        withwindow{Parent window}){true}

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a potantial issue in Geb alert handling while switching windows. Would you do me a favour please and post this as an issue in [the tracker](https://github.com/geb/issues/issues) including the code and stacktraces you provided? I’ll take a look when I’m back from holidays in a couple of weeks.

Comment: In the mean while, can you please share Information on ways to approaching this problem. I am searching for 2 days and nothing worked. I am thinking you might have a better understanding about this and efficient ways to try.

Comment: I looked closer and this might be caused by whatever happens when the dialog is accepted. Does it by any chance close the newly opened window? If that’s the case then you will have to revert to using the native WebDriver dialog handling because Geb is doing some cleanup after the dialog confirmation is clicked and if the window has already been closed then it will fail.

Comment: Yes, the new window gets closed once withConfirm() is executed and also it gives me this error when I include withConfirm(). FYI, everything works fine when I execute without withConfirm().  Can you please explain what's native webDriver dialog handling. In GEB documentation I see withConfirm() is the only way useful for my case.

Comment: How do I assert the withConfirm I am using like this like this :                    assert withConfirm(true){$("tr.oddListRowS1:first-child a",0).click()}.text().contains("This record") . Because My dialog box have more text, am checking for first two words using .contains()

Comment: This tutorial explains native WebDriver dialog handling:  https://www.guru99.com/alert-popup-handling-selenium.html